# Distance matrix not giving nearest point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity, census, distance-matrix

I'm having a bit of trouble with my procedures in QGIS Desktop 3.22.6.

I bring in a shapefile for the entire US block groups into QGIS. I then bring in points of stores across the U.S. I then use the centroid algorithm to create centroids, and then use the distance matrix to get the nearest 1 point (store).

Visually inspecting the points and centroid:
[image]

When I examine the results, I get this:
[image: Distance matrix results]

The issue I have is twofold:

1. The nearest point isn't the '202589' observation when it should be
2. If I include other points (stores), the nearest '202589' point isn't even included if I select the nearest 4.
3. Lastly, will this make any difference if I do this for the entire U.S., even with all of Alaska and Hawaii?

The projection is EPSG:4269 - NAD83 and the block group examining is in Alaska if that makes any difference.

I'm still relatively new to geospatial work.

Comment: Hi! This is an issue related to the way the tool is currently designed. The Distance field is filled with the ellipsoidal distance, while the k nearest points filter works based on Cartesian distances (a very problematic issue if the coordinate system of the points layer is geographic, because then the Cartesian distances are a kind of "flat degrees"). If the number of points allows it, the best thing would be to remove the filter of k nearest points (k=0) and choose the nearest ones based on the values of the Distance field.

Comment: I saw that suggestion elsewhere; however, I do not think it's feasible in my case given I have 65,000+ locations and 217,000 block groups as comparison.

Comment: So you should reproject the layers to a coordinate system that doesn't distort the distances in your area of work too much. There you could apply the filter so that distances are calculated only for some of the nearest points based on the layer's CRS, and then choose the nearest one based on the Distance field.

Comment: Also, try to edit the post so that a single question is clearly visible (the three-dot enumeration doesn't help to understand what you're asking), so we can reopen and answer it. Welcome!